# Are the empty set and a singleton set totally ordered sets?

Tags: order-theory

Are the empty set and a singleton set totally ordered sets?

I think yes, but I'm struggling to name the unique linear order for them.

This is what I think, I understand.

To a set A be totally ordered or linear ordered, these two conditions need to hold.

- R is transitive
- R has the trichotomy property over A

For the empty set, since is empty, I can't say that it doesn't hold those conditions. {} x {} = {}
So, I think the unique order for an empty set is an empty set, but how do I write an ordered pair?

For the case of a singleton.
Since a singleton set only has one element, I don't have another number to compare it with, so the trichotomy property doesn't hold.

1! = 1, so it has a unique order,
But how do I write it?

Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Being pedantic, the base set alone is not an ordered set. The order relation must be given. For the empty set, it would be the empty relation (happens to be itself) is the only order it admits. For a singleton $\{x\}$, its only order is $\{(x,x)\}$. Remember that the conditions in the definition of partial/total order are implications. If there are no elements to satisfy their hypotheses, they are true.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the details right here depends on whether you think of orders in terms of the strict order relation $x < y$ or the weak order relation $x \le y$. For both the empty set and the singleton the strict order is empty, in the sense that as a relation thought of as a subset of $X \times X$ it's the empty set. The empty relation is [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) transitive and vacuously satisfies trichotomy. For the singleton the unique weak order relation is equality, and for the empty set even the weak order relation is still empty.

Note that if $X$ is empty then so is $X \times X$, so the empty set has a unique relation on it, and this relation satisfies a bunch of conditions vacuously. If $X$ is the singleton then so is $X \times X$, so the singleton has exactly two relations on it, one of which is empty and one of which is the equality relation.

You can think of every set as having three canonically defined relations on it: the empty relation, the equality relation, and the "complete" relation (I don't know if there's a standard term for this) corresponding to all of $X \times X$. It's a funny fact about the singleton that the equality and complete relations are the same, and it's a funny fact about the empty set that all three relations are the same. It's a third funny fact that none of these relations define strict or weak orders on a set with more than one element.

Comment: I'm confused, "For a singleton {x}, its only order is {(x,x)}." but it doesn't hold trichotomy. Didn't I need at least 2 elements for trichotomy to hold?

Comment: @Annai: you are confusing the strict and the weak order. The strict order is empty, $\{ (x, x) \}$ is the weak order. Let's be clear about exactly what trichotomy says: it says that if $a, b$ are two elements then exactly one of $a < b, a = b, a > b$ holds. For the empty relation on the singleton $\{ x \}$ we have $x = x$ so the equality case holds. (You may have seen a different statement of trichotomy that involves only two cases for $a \neq b$; that version of trichotomy holds vacuously here. But this is the better statement, because *tri*chotomy is supposed to have *three* cases.)

Comment: Yes, I don't know about strict and weak order. I just started to learn about linear order, but I'm so confused, there are so many names; chain, totally ordered, well ordered, are all those the same? I'm still not sure what is the unique linear order for the singleton :( . How do I write a linear order? A set with ordered pairs? Can you please explain it to me. thanks.

Comment: @Annai: as I've said, there just are two different conventions here and the answer is different depending on which one you're using. Since you mention trichotomy you are talking about the strict order, and the strict order is *empty* on the singleton: that is, it is the *empty* set of ordered pairs.